# Eclipse SVN Check Out Multiple Folders to 1 Project

Tags: eclipse, svn

Is it possible to checkout several directories into one project in Eclipse?

I have the following directory:

```
JS
  app
  css
  icons
```

I want to check out js/app and js/css into one project.

I've been looking everywhere but can't seem to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, it is possible. But you could checkout the whole directory, and ignore the icons directory. Depending on the language you are using and the perspective, there is sometimes the notion of a "source folder". You can then mark `app` and `css` as source folders (so they stand out in Eclipse and are clearly separated from the rest). Could you add the distro you are using (Standard Java, Java EE, ... )? And could you please add information to the subversion client you are using: Subversive, Subclipse, or svn cmd client or TortoiseSVN?

Comment: I'm using Collabnet with subversive. I ended up just creating individual projects for each. I don't think it's possible.